# Outlook add-in Permission Denied

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I get the following error when trying to read headers in an email:

```
code: 7000   
message: "You don't have sufficient permissions for this action."    
name: "Permission Denied"
```

I'm using the new version of Outlook for Mac 16.41 and the latest iOS version. In both apps, I can't read the headers in the selected email, even though **it works on the Web or on the old version of Outlook.**

I'm using the following method to load the headers:

```
private _loadHeaders(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(({ status, value, error }) => {                
            if (status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                const header = value.replace(/[\r\n]+? ?=\?[a-z\-]+\?[A-Z]{1}\?([\S]+)\?=?/g, (_, data) => data.replace("=2E", ".").replace("=5F", "_"));
                return resolve(header);
            } else {
                return reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

and have the following permissions in my manifest:

```
<Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that `getAllInternetHeadersAsync` is only available in `requirement set 1.8` which is not supported by the iOS or the modern mac app in August 2020. The solution is to use Exchange rest requests. I'm sharing the code I used, in case anyone might need it in the future (typescript).

```
private get _itemRestId() {
    if (this._mailbox.diagnostics.hostName === 'OutlookIOS') {
        // itemId is already REST-formatted
        return this._mailbox.item.itemId;
    } else {
        // Convert to an item ID for API v2.0
        return this._mailbox.convertToRestId(
            this._mailbox.item.itemId,
            Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0
        );
    }
}

private get _headersUrl() {
    return `${this._restUrl}/v2.0/me/messages/${this._itemRestId}?$select=*,internetMessageHeaders`;
}

private get _accessToken(): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this._mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, ({ status, value, error }) => {
            if (status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                return resolve(value);
            } else {
                return reject(error)
            }
        });
    });
}

get headers(): Promise<string> {
    return this._accessToken
        .then(accessToken => fetch(this._headersUrl, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/text',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
            }
        }))
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => data.InternetMessageHeaders.reduce((carry, item) => `${carry}\n\r${item.Name}: ${item.Value}`, ""));
}
```

Comment: That is right. This API is available in 1.8 which is available only in old Outlook (New Outlook: off). You can check which API set is available by using this code: 

if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('Mailbox', '1.8')) {
  console.log("Yes");
}
else {
 console.log("No");
}